# gfortran in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, fortran

I hope my message will get read soon and somebody will give me a solution.
I use fortran to do simulation and `gfortran` is the compiler I use. Recently I migrated from Ubuntu 10.10 to 12.10.

After installing `gfortran` then I tried to compile and run my fortran programs then the problem started. I successfully compiled the program but I am unable to execute it. (I work in a directory in shared partition, not in `HOME` directory). When I compiled the program and run it within `HOME` directory, everything worked fine. On my Ubuntu 10.10, I was able to compile and execute fortran program from everywhere not only within `HOME` directory.

This is what I do for compiling and executing fortran program:

```
gfortran hello.f90 -o hello # to compile it
./hello # to execute it
```

I'm blind about `PATH` or anything like it (this has to do with it, I suspect) so please give me direction.

Comment: Do you get any sort of message when attempting to run the executable in the shared partition? A likely cause would seem to be that the partition is mounted with the `noexec` option.

Answer (score 1):

On the file that you produced do:

```
ls -l ./hello
```

It's likely the file does not have execute permissions. You may see something like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mark mark 2 Dec 18 11:37 hello
```

but what you need is something like this:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mark mark 135163 Dec 18 11:39 hello
```

To get to this state use the command:

```
chmod gu+x ./hello
```

This command gives group and user execute permissions. Then try the above `ls` command again. See if you can execute it now.